# What is advantage and disadvantage of implementing single user session?

Tags: security, session

Before posting this question I searched and found that lot of questions were asked on "how to implement single user session" in different tools or frameworks.
But my question is why should we implement single user sessions?

I discussed with some friends and did some research on Google and I could find two reasons:
1. Some applications can potentially maintain "user working state" of a user, so if they allow more than one sessions then it can mess up the "user working state". 
2. Some tools/applications need this for implementing licensing. Because the license allows only fixed number of users so implementing "single user session" will prevent the misuse.

Both of the above points are not related to security. Is there any other reason why it is considered a good security practice?

Thanks,
Manish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a security point of view, single user sessions can help a user detect that their account is being used elsewhere. For example, upon logon if a user receives a message that their account is already logged on at another location, they will be alerted to the fact that their  credentials have been compromised and that they should perhaps change their password.

Apart from that, I can only think of it being a good security mechanism to protect content (i.e. licensing that you covered in point (2)). However, there may be a secondary advantage to preventing multiple logons per account - users are less likely to share their credentials with other users if the account cannot be used simultaneously. Therefore their account details are likely to be kept more secure as the details have not been emailed to friends or colleagues.